# Getting data by logged in user id c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

i am using the membership provider from visual studio.

i created a new column called background_Image in the membership table

now i want each time the user logs in gets his own background image that he/she uploaded.
it's like getting the username but i didn't know how to do it just getting that column.

i know it has something to do with current user but not sure how to do it. 
Get by current user and getting that data from that specific column.

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

This one get the name but i need to get the data from the background column.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't store this data using membership, it's not really what it is designed for. This sort of data is more to do with your application than the identity of your user. Instead have a look at using something like entity framework code first to store/retrieve the data in (I assume you are using) sql server. The entity/table should probably have properties for:

ID to uniquely identify it
The users id (from Identity as you suggest perhaps)
The background image file/name/path etc

Comment: yeah but the question is how can i get that background image from the logged in user ? 
i am using dataset and objects... but i got a little lost when it came to get by current user.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can get current logedin user name by

```
var userId = (Guid)(Membership.GetUser(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name ,false).ProviderUserKey);
```

Now we have current log-in `userid`,

Now you can use select query for your membership table where userId. This query return that row, and you can get that column value.